# docker and image size limit

Tags: image, docker, size, containers

I've been reading a lot about this issue in here and other websites, but I haven't manage to find a proper solution on how to increase the images size limit which is set to 10GB by default.

A bit of background informations.

I'm building a docker container:
https://bitbucket.org/efestolab/docker-buildgaffer

Which download and builds a consistent set of libraries on top of a centos image. (takes a horrible amount of time and space to build)

The problem is that every single time I try to build it I hit this error :

```
No space left on device
```

Docker version:

```
Docker version 1.7.1, build 786b29d
```

Docker Info :

```
Containers: 1
Images: 76
Storage Driver: devicemapper
Pool Name: docker-8:7-12845059-pool
Pool Blocksize: 65.54 kB
Backing Filesystem: extfs
Data file: /dev/loop0
Metadata file: /dev/loop1
Data Space Used: 11.28 GB
Data Space Total: 107.4 GB
Data Space Available: 96.1 GB
Metadata Space Used: 10.51 MB
Metadata Space Total: 2.147 GB
Metadata Space Available: 2.137 GB
Udev Sync Supported: false
Deferred Removal Enabled: false
Data loop file: /home/_varlibdockerfiles/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
Metadata loop file: /home/_varlibdockerfiles/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
Library Version: 1.02.82-git (2013-10-04)
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Logging Driver: json-file
Kernel Version: 3.15.9-031509-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
CPUs: 8
Total Memory: 15.58 GiB
Name: hdd-XPS-15-9530
ID: 2MEF:IYLS:MCN5:AR5O:6IXJ:3OB3:DGJE:ZC4N:YWFD:7AAB:EQ73:LKXQ
Username: efesto
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: No swap limit support
```

After stopping the service and nuking the /var/lib/docker folder,
I've been updating by docker startup script

```
/lib/systemd/system/docker.service
```

with these flags :

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker -d --storage-opt dm.basesize=20G --storage-opt dm.loopdatasize=256G -H fd:// $DOCKER_OPTS
```

and restarted docker service, but still fails with the same error.

I've also been reading that might be due to the original image I'm rely on (centos:6), which might have been built with 10GB limit.

So I rebuild the centos6 image, and used that as base for mine, but I did hit the same error.

Does anyone have a reliable way to make me able to build this docker image fully ?

If there's any other informations which might be useful, just feel free to ask.

Thanks for any reply or suggestions !
L.

Comment: I have been unable to find your Dockerfile in your various links, where is it?

Comment: Couldn't it be the case that simply your disk is full? I mean the disk where the docker daemon runs? Your `docker info` says: `Data Space Total: 107.4 GB`

Comment: Hi  @user2915097, here is the docker file : https://bitbucket.org/efestolab/docker-buildgaffer/src/aedc69cdcfe5b8eff6213d79175c5a646e8470c8/Dockerfile?at=master

Comment: Hi @h3nrik, thought the same a the beginning, but there's plenty of space available. (note, /var/lib/docker has been symlinked to the /home partition for more space as well.)

here you can see that is the image not going over 10Gb:

`code`<none>              <none>              9dbd4ea10477        19 hours ago        9.825 GB `code`

Comment: The last 2 lines of your Dockerfile are strange `VOLUME /$OUT_FOLDER
CMD cp -Rf -v /opt/* /$OUT_FOLDER && bash` usually, the last line of a Dockerfile is either a CMD or ENTRYPOINT my_executable

Comment: @user2915097
correct, usually is CMD or ENTRYPOINT, but in this case, there's no point of using these, as it doesn't have to run anything once built. it only has to drop on the host disk the built libraries.

Comment: I have launched a `docker build -t mytag .` with your Dockerfile, waiting for completion

Comment: Will be taking hours to break as it has to get to 10GB, be ready to wait. Thanks.

Comment: @user2915097: hang on. master will be building without problem as stays under 10Gb. Use branch Applications:
https://bitbucket.org/efestolab/docker-buildgaffer/src/71c901b299d06c06f82fe59a1ef659082283e9fc/Dockerfile?at=applications

it will be breaking half way through building cortex : https://bitbucket.org/efestolab/docker-buildgaffer/src/71c901b299d06c06f82fe59a1ef659082283e9fc/Dockerfile?at=applications#Dockerfile-486

Comment: by the way, try to reduce the number of RUN in your Dockerfile

Comment: It should be building bigger intermediate containers, as far as I understand.
RUN commands are kept it in a way that if something breaks during a build, the container remain in a consistent state , eg: source file will have to be decompressed , configured and built.

Comment: I have built successfully the previous Dockerfile, the image has a size of 9,65 Gb, I am building the other

Comment: built successfully, size 13,99 GB

Comment: Ok this is good, how did you manage?

Comment: nothing special, just did `docker build -t gaffer1 .` and got at the end  `Step 90 : VOLUME /$OUT_FOLDER
 ---> Running in 5bc5bfb236a8
 ---> b641fdd75aaf
Removing intermediate container 5bc5bfb236a8
Step 91 : CMD cp -Rf -v /opt/* /$OUT_FOLDER && bash
 ---> Running in 7a4ea27e74f9
 ---> c5af0805fcb6
Removing intermediate container 7a4ea27e74f9
Successfully built c5af0805fcb6
` My host is Ubuntu 14.04 64 bits, my docker version is 1.8.0-rc3

Comment: `docker images gaffer1
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
gaffer1             latest              c5af0805fcb6        12 hours ago        13.99 GB
`

Comment: Could you post your Docker info?

Comment: here it is `docker info
Containers: 79
Images: 1617
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 1777
 Dirperm1 Supported: false
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Logging Driver: json-file
Kernel Version: 3.13.0-53-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
CPUs: 8
Total Memory: 7.72 GiB
Name: gg-P15SM-A-SM1-A
ID: 227E:JM7R:FRAA:PTTY:PG2U:XNJU:ZCDD:JO5C:IN3Y:SJXU:HASA:6NLI
Username: k3ck3c
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: No swap limit support
`

Comment: Aufs might be the answer at this issue?

Comment: Thanks for the tests.

Answer (score 5):

Found [this article](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003812129-Overcoming-Container-Storage-Limitation)

Basically edit /etc/docker/daemon.json file to include

```
"storage-opts": [
        "dm.basesize=40G"
]
```

Restart the docker service, and it will enable to create/import images larger than 10Gb

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the test of @user2915097, I've been updating kernel version 3.16.0, installed the kernel extras, and removed and re installed docker.
the problem seems to be addressable to devicemapper, now without any change in the docker command I get:

```
Containers: 0
Images: 94
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /home/_varlibdockerfiles/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 94
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Logging Driver: json-file
Kernel Version: 3.16.0-45-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
CPUs: 8
Total Memory: 15.58 GiB
Name: hdd-XPS-15-9530
ID: 2MEF:IYLS:MCN5:AR5O:6IXJ:3OB3:DGJE:ZC4N:YWFD:7AAB:EQ73:LKXQ
Username: efesto
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: No swap limit support
```

and it finally builds images > 10GB.
L.

Comment: I'm also running into this. Any chance of showing the actual fix?

Comment: Hi sorry for the delay, there's no real actual fix, just to update the kernel version, and reinstalled docker. That was it, I had an old version.

Answer (score 0):

Since this question has been asked, the storage driver here:

> `Storage Driver: devicemapper`

is no longer used by default, and not recommended. That also means the settings for the 10GB limit no longer apply.

The `overlay2` storage driver (currently enabled by default) does not have size limits of it's own. Instead, the underlying filesystem you use for `/var/lib/docker` is used for any available free space and inodes there. You can check that free space with:

```bash
df -h /var/lib/docker
df -ih /var/lib/docker
```

Answer (score -1):

after modifing  the docker daemon startup parameters do the following

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl stop docker
rm -rf /var/lib/docker/*
systemctl start docker
```

This will remove all your images, make sure you save them before

eg `docker save -o something.tar.gz image_name`

and reload them after starting docker

eg `docker load -i something.tar.gz`