# How to increase size of a docker image?

Tags: docker

When using `docker build -t test .` to build my app, I get the error:

```
Error processing tar file(exit status 1): write /target/myapp.jar: no space left on device
```

How can I increase the limit of the device that docker refers to?

Comment: the docker image is 20GB and I have >100GB free disk space.

Comment: what does `df -h` print?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [docker and image size limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31883782/docker-and-image-size-limit)

Comment: Not fully. The top answer says reinstall the kernel and docker. I installed docker yesterday, so it's up-to-date. I guess the kernel would be too.

Answer (score 0):

You can try do the following:

- Remove dangling images: `docker rmi -f $(docker images -f "dangling=true" -q)`
- Remove volumes that're not in use
- List all containers: `docker ps -a` and remove containers that you don't need anymore

You can also use `docker system prune` that removes several things (and since 17.06.1 you can also pass `--volumes` to prune unused volumes), but I think you should try the previous steps before.

Comment: I used these commands but still get "no space left on device"

Comment: @greatguytoanswerto did you try `docker system prune --volumes`?

Comment: yes, I ran that too. It outputs: total reclaimed space: 0B.